Displaying children item of Listview
I had a demo for list view to display menu having parent and child. I simply added items into list view, but the result is only parent item is showing. How can I get to show my list view including both parent and children items?
My debug result is having 2 child items in parent. But can't display. Is it binding problem?
<Page.Resources>
<DataTemplate x:Key="ParentDataTemplate">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14"/>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="ChildDataTemplate">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="20,0,0,0"/>
</DataTemplate>

<local:MenuItemTemplateSelector x:Key="MenuItemTemplateSelector"
                                ParentTemplate="{StaticResource ParentDataTemplate}"
                                ChildTemplate="{StaticResource ChildDataTemplate}"/>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid>
<muxc:ListView x:Name="nestedListView" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MenuItemTemplateSelector}">
    <muxc:ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="muxc:ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        </Style>
    </muxc:ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

    <muxc:ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" MaximumRowsOrColumns="2"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </muxc:ListView.ItemsPanel>
</muxc:ListView>
</Grid>

this is my cs code.
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        // Creating a parent item
        MenuItem parentItem = new MenuItem
        {
            Name = "Parent Item 1"
        };

        // Creating child items
        MenuItem childItem1 = new MenuItem { Name = "Child Item 1" };
        MenuItem childItem2 = new MenuItem { Name = "Child Item 2" };

        // Adding child items to the parent
        parentItem.Children.Add(childItem1);
        parentItem.Children.Add(childItem2);

        MenuItemViewModel viewModel = new MenuItemViewModel();
        viewModel.MenuItems.Add(parentItem);

        nestedListView.ItemsSource = viewModel.MenuItems;
    }
}

public class MenuItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<MenuItem> Children { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<MenuItem>();
}

public class MenuItemViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<MenuItem> MenuItems { get; } = new ObservableCollection<MenuItem>();
}

public class MenuItemTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate ParentTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate ChildTemplate { get; set; }

    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item is MenuItem menuItem)
        {
            return menuItem.Children.Count > 0 ? ChildTemplate : ParentTemplate;
        }
        return base.SelectTemplateCore(item, container);
    }
}


Have you tried the TreeView?

@AndrewKeepCoding yes, it was the same case. not showing children.

Check my answer.

As I mentioned in my comment, you should use the TreeView for this:
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate
        x:Key="ParentDataTemplate"
        x:DataType="local:MenuItem">
        <TreeViewItem
            Content="{x:Bind Name}"
            FontSize="14"
            FontWeight="Bold"
            ItemsSource="{x:Bind Children}" />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate
        x:Key="ChildDataTemplate"
        x:DataType="local:MenuItem">
        <TextBlock
            Margin="20,0,0,0"
            Text="{x:Bind Name}" />
    </DataTemplate>

    <local:MenuItemTemplateSelector
        x:Key="MenuItemTemplateSelector"
        ChildTemplate="{StaticResource ChildDataTemplate}"
        ParentTemplate="{StaticResource ParentDataTemplate}" />
</Page.Resources>

<Grid>
    <TreeView
        x:Name="nestedListView"
        ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MenuItemTemplateSelector}" />
</Grid>

and, IIRC, you also need to change the method to override in DataTemplateSelector:
public class MenuItemTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate ParentTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate ChildTemplate { get; set; }

    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item)
    {
        if (item is MenuItem menuItem)
        {
            return menuItem.Children.Count > 0 ? ParentTemplate : ChildTemplate;
        }

        return base.SelectTemplateCore(item);
    }
}

